# Get access to result sets from one stored procedure inside another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure that have 5 Select statements and as I understand when I run it I get 5 result sets.

I'm also using Sql server reporting services to generate some reports.

I would like to run that stored procedure from ssrs and put there 3 of 5 result sets. I read that it is currently impossible because only one (top first) result set is taken by ssrs.

So my idea was to create second stored procedure that would execute first one and union 3 out of 5 result sets and return only one newly created result set. But I have no idea how to iterate/or get access to result sets in stored procedure from executed stored procedure.

Also when I execute stored procedure from stored procedure I can see that result sets from first one are also printed in sql server management studio so I believe that problem will be the same when moving to SSRS.

Do you have any hints on how can I access results sets from one stored procedure in another, manipulate them and make sure that only newly created result set will be returned so that I can use it in SSRS?

thanks!

Comment: It's impossible to do this from T-SQL. Either do it via Powershell, or rewrite it as five separate procedures or table valued functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a table variable or temp table to save your results. Then execute the other stored procedures and insert the results into that table. Then return the results of that table variable.

Example below.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC StoredProc1
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT
      1,
      'ValueColumn1SP1',
      'ValueColumn2';

END;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC StoredProc2
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT
      1,
      'ValueColumn1SP2',
      'ValueColumn2';

END;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC CombinedSP
AS
BEGIN

   /*create a table to store results, can also be an temp table*/
   DECLARE @CombinedResults TABLE
   (
      Id INT,
      Column1 VARCHAR(50),
      Column2 VARCHAR(50)
   );

   /*Execute first Stored Proc and enter results into table*/
   INSERT INTO @CombinedResults
   (
      Id,
      Column1,
      Column2
   )
   EXEC dbo.StoredProc1;

   /*Execute second Stored Proc and enter results into table*/
   INSERT INTO @CombinedResults
   (
      Id,
      Column1,
      Column2
   )
   EXEC dbo.StoredProc2;
   /*etc*/


   /*retrieve data*/
   SELECT *
   FROM   @CombinedResults AS cr;

END;
GO

/*execute combined SP*/
EXEC CombinedSP;
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that currently I have one stored procedure that has 5 select statements. I don't want to split it into 5 different stored procedures for various reasons (it is used by other parts of the system).